# How to make my element take 100% of the screen width even if it is inside an element that take 80% of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am working on a ReactJS project and  I am facing a CSS problem. I will explain exactly what I want to achieve and what I have done so far.

My fluidContainer is the div with the gray background.

Here is what I have now :

[image]

And here is what I want to achieve, I want that space to be eliminated :

[image]

I used negative margins and made my fluid-container larger but it is bad code for me, so here is my react component :

```
const FluidContainer = props => (
    <div
       className="co-fluid-container"
   >
        {props.children}
    </div>
);
```

And here is my sass file and what I have tried already :

```
@import "../../appConstants/style/cssVariables.scss";
.co-fluid-container {

//TODO: améliorer la précision
margin: 0 ( calc( (#{$container-width} + (#{$grid-gutter}/2) - 99vw) /2) );
padding: 40px (calc((100vw - #{$container-width} - (#{$grid-gutter}/2))/2));

&--fluid-content {
   padding: 40px 20px;
}

@media($extra-small){
  // a justifier
  width:calc(100vw + #{$grid-gutter}*5);
  margin-left: calc(-#{$grid-gutter}*3/2);
}
@media($small) {
  // a justifier
  width: calc(100vw + #{$grid-gutter}*5);
  margin: 0 calc(-#{$grid-gutter}*3);
  padding: 40px calc(#{$grid-gutter}*3);
}

@media($medium){
  width:calc(110vw);
  margin-left: calc(-#{$grid-gutter}*3/2);
  padding: 40px calc(#{$grid-gutter}*3);
}

@media($large){
  margin: 0 ( calc( (#{$container-width} + (#{$grid-gutter}/2) - 100vw) /2));
  padding: 40px (calc((100vw - #{$container-width} - (#{$grid-gutter}/2))/2));

}
}
```

This code is causing me problem, when I try to make my page responsive, here are the variables I used in my code :

```
grid-gutter : 32 px;
container: 1170px;
extra-small: "max-width: 599px"
medium and large and small are breakpoints too ..
```

Here is a solution I have tried also, is using relative and absolute positioning but still get a problem, so I changed my rendered element to this :

```
const FluidContainer = props => (
    <div className="co-fluid-conteneur">
        <div className="co-fluid-container">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
);
```

and that is my style :

```
.co-fluid-conteneur {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}

.co-fluid-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

but those are the results :

[image]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: absolute positioning... ?

Comment: you are deleted your old question and repost it

Comment: @Vencovsky Explain more ?

Comment: If you set an elements css Position Attribute to position: absolute; it will have its position set relative to the first parent element with a css Position of relative. However you would then be able to set the width to whatever you like without constraint.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how about moving my div to the left, I will still have to use negative values for margin or left properties to do that ? no ?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick example:

Take the code for the main html file or element as:

```
<div className="parent">
  <div className="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 50vw;
   height: 50vh;
   background-color: blue;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 40vh;
   background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

This will produce the following layout. (vw is a measure of the viewport width, so 50vw is 50% of the Viewport Width).

[image: Example of the layout]

Comment: Check my update, I guess I tried your solution, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Without seeing the code or looking at all the css I can't be completely sure. However I would image looking at it that the "co-fluid-conteneur" Either has a margin on the left side or that a parent of that element has a margin or padding. Work your way back up the element tree and see if anything else has a margin or padding, I can't give you a precise work-around as I don't know your code structure and css is specific like that.

Comment: Yes, there is a parent having a margin and padding in the left, ( both ), what I was looking for is something that can be done and ignore the parent code .. is it possible ?

Comment: if you set the Left property of the child element to -(margin of the parent) that will position how you want. So say the parents margin is 10px, set the child's Left: -10px, should solve this. CSS is brutal..